# About a concept about blockchain during learning

Tags: blockchain

Like a example blockchain has one core block in its Ledger/chain. Every time who used (new or old user) blockchain from his node that will clone all chain/all blocks , means one core block (because there will be decentralised storage instead of centralised storage) .But if  a block contain 1 mb storage info then it will be consumed 1 core mb storage in Laptop or PC ( node).

**My Question is what will be for Laptop storage?**

Comment: Hi, can you re-write the question? I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: If you have full nodes when you synchronize you need to download all blocks. If you have a PC and a laptop full nodes then each will have a full copy of the blockchain. Ethereum implements light nodes that will only download the data they need.

Answer (score 3):

Blockchain data can be stored on NoSQL databases such as MongoDB or cassandra because they can hold any type of data in object form also they are available at cheaper rates for companies which allows you to host your blockchain. Example of such databases is BigChainDB which is not fully decentralized but uses nodes in a network to store blockchain data along with third party database providers.

Comment: According to blockchain every  node will have a same instance of distributed ledger, so every time it will copy all data from the database storage?

Comment: cloud storage does not means , whole data of blockchain is stored on a single cloud , it is distributed over several clouds and servers. If we take evildage example that we have 5 people then they will have their data on different cloud sources.  Suppose we have A ,B ,C ,D ,E and A have 100 Tokkens and A gave 10 tokens to B then balance is A = 90 and B = 10 this information is also updated on leger of C , D , E along with A, B. Therefore even if cloud of A goes down we have updated data in cloud storages of B,C,D,E so A can update his ledger again.

Comment: It will not copy anything , any changes made in blockchain is through consensus and done to all nodes therefore all nodes will be updated with same data. And if any node goes down then that node will goto genesis block and traverse all blocks and will update its ledger to latest (similar to other nodes in network.) . example - suppose 3 people in a network made 100 transactions with agreement and have updated legers but somehow 1 of them lost its data then it will goto starting block and traverse all 100 transactions now he have updated ledger with other two.

Answer (score 1):

A blockchain is a chain of connected blocks( data structure which holds data ).
Firstly , we have genesis block which is a parent block of a blockchain.

now suppose there are 5 people in blockchain then a shared ledger will be mained for each of them , and that ledger is not created on their laptops(it can be but not necessary). You can store blockchain data on cloud storages as they are cheap and faster when used in bulk. 
For example BigChainDB , or on servers. 
Like we have several testnets such as rinkeby , kovan etc they have their own servers and databases so you can create and deploy blockchain and you data will be stored in those db.

Comment: If it is cloud storages then it centralised server again!!!

Comment: if someone delete the cloud server then what will be the security?